# Bootstrap Dropdown not working after ajax form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am submitting a form via ajax using jquery. The form submits successfully but the dropdown menus made using bootstrap stops working after submission.

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    jQuery.each(jQuery('#upload')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        formData.append('file-'+i, file);
    });
    var agentname=$('#agentname').val();
    var bio=$('#bio').val();


    $("#success").html("<img src='loading.gif' height='40' width='40'></img>");
    var datastring='agentname='+agentname+'&bio='+bio;
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:'agentsubmit.php?'+datastring,
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#success").html(result);
        }
    });

});


});
```

After reading other answers i found out that this might be because i am using the e.preventDefault() function in my code. I tried removing the preventDefault  function but the form stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using click function for the '#submit' button can you try changing your code to bind to the form 'submit' function.

As explained at this example - http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Changed the code to the submit function instead of click now the dropdown work after even number of clicks on submit button. Like if i click once on submit button, the dropdown would stop working if i click on submit again it starts working again

Comment: Just checked my original code is doing the same thing